# Scientific and Gerneral notation in awk

Tags: awk

I am puzzeled by the differences in the following two awk-lines:

```
$ cat a.txt
1
$ awk '{$2=$1/1982300000 ;$3 = $2 * 0.05}{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' a.txt
1   5.04465e-10 2.52232e-11
$ awk '{$2=$1/1.98*10^09 ;$3 = $2 * 0.05}{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' a.txt
1   5.05051e+08 2.52525e+07
```

I think I am writing the exponential notation in awk somehow wrong can you please correct

Comment: try putting a decimal after the 1982300000. and see if that gives you more consistency.

Comment: if i put parenthesis around 1.98*10^09 i get same result i.e. $1/(1.98*10^09)

Answer (score 1):

here

```
$ echo 1 | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, a=$1/(1.98*10^9), a*0.05}' 
1       5.05051e-10     2.52525e-11
```

you need add parenthesis, otherwise the second multiplication (10^9) is not in the denominator.

Or, you can use the `e` notation

```
$ echo 1 | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, a=$1/1.98e9, a*0.05}'
```

which doesn't require extra parans.

Comment: thank you infact i added parenthesis i am glad to know that e and E work in awk

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here you have to take into account:

1. Numbers that are written in scientific notation of the form *1.23 × 10<sup>-4</sup>* are best written in E-notation when it boils down to programming. The most common form of E-notation is `1.23E4` or `1.23e4`.

   When you would write `1.23*10^4` (under the assumption that `^` represents *Exponentiation*), you will actively perform an exponentiation operation to compute how much `10^4` is, followed by a  multiplication of two numbers. This looks very expensive to define a single number.
2. Multiplication is not associative with a division. This means that `a/b*c` is different from `a/(b*c)`.

Hence, the solution to your problem is thus:

- Use E-notation:

  ```
    awk '{$2=$1/1.98e9 ;$3 = $2 * 0.05}{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' a.txt
  ```
- Or add brackets:

  ```
    awk '{$2=$1/(1.98*10^9) ;$3 = $2 * 0.05}{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' a.txt
  ```

Comment: thank you infact i added parenthesis i am glad to know that e and E work in awk